# Creating a formula or macro to sum across age ranges in different tables

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I currently have 3 tables that are separated into Person, Women, and Men, and their percentage breakouts in a product I am analyzing. The data looks something like this:

```
Person
Age | Percent Breakout
13-17 | 1%
18-20 | 2%
...

Women
Age | Percent Breakout
13-17 | 0.2%
18-20 | 1%
...

Men
Age | Percent Breakout
13-17 | 0.8%
18-20 | 1%
```

What I was wondering was how I could create a formula or a macro which will help me calculate the breakouts given filtering by whether it is person, women, or men, and also the beginning number for the age range and the end number for the age range.

Right now, I have a skeleton set up where I have data validated dropdown cells where I have:

```
Demographic: Person, Women, Men
Age Start: 13,18,21,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,65+
Age End: 17,20,24,29,34,39,44,49,54,64,65+
```

Now I'm trying to create an if statement which will first check which table to look at, then check the number at the beginning of the range, check the number at the end of the range, and through that criteria, sum up all of the relevant percentages.

I feel like there's definitely a straightforward way to do this, and I would love some help!

Comment: [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b), and the ranges change based on demographic.  Something like `SUMIFS(IF(<demographic="Person",<Person Percent column>,IF(<demographic="Men",<Men Percent column>,.....` etc

Answer (score 0):

You can setup something like this to start:

[image]

`=VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$13,MATCH(G3,$A$1:$D$1,0),1)`

The key here in `VLOOKUP` is the 4th parameter needs to set to `TRUE` or `1`.  This will find the closest match so you just need the start points (don't need to input a range) in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Building on ian's post, you will need the sunproduct to be able to sum all the percentages for any given "range"
The first 3 parts check for a true false on every intersection giving a 1 or 0 and the last part (b2:d13) is the numbers you want summed.
[image]